# Remove jQuery document keypress event, but only for object that set it

Tags: jquery

In a class, I'm setting the keypress event of `document`:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) { .. });
```

When I unload the properties of the class, the document's keypress event is still set. I could obviously just unset the document's keypress event, however I don't want to remove a document keypress event that's set in another javascript object.

I know jQuery can "chain" multiple functions for the same object and event, so is there a way to target which function should be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try tagging your `keydown` event handler. Something like this:

```
$(document).on('keydown.foo', function () { ... });
```

That way you can unbind *this one* specifically, leaving the rest intact:

```
$(document).off('keydown.foo');
```

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know that was possible. Thanks!